Can't find the 'on' button on a Waveshare SIM7600G-H-PCIE connected to my Raspberry Pi. How do I turn it on?
I have a Waveshare 4G modem (Waveshare SIM7600G-H-PCIE) connected to my Raspberry Pi that I can't figure out how to turn on. I can get it to make a little bit of noise but all other attempts end in an error.
I have it connected to one of these:

PCIe to M.2 4G/5G And USB 3.2 HAT for Raspberry Pi 5, Compatible with SIMCom/Quectel 4G/5G modules, Raspberry Pi 5 HAT, High-speed Networking

My best guess is that I can't figure out how to even turn it on. How do I turn this Waveshare on or get it to make more noise. My end goal is a custom router.
Here are my attempts with mmcli:
CLI noise:
pi5-dev:~ $ sudo mmcli -m 0
  -------------------------
  General |           path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
  -------------------------
  System  |         device: /sys/devices/platform/axi/1000110000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-1
          |        drivers: cdc_acm, cdc_ncm
          |         plugin: generic
          |   primary port: ttyACM0
          |          ports: eth1 (net), eth2 (net), eth3 (net), ttyACM0 (at)
  -------------------------
  Status  |          state: failed
          |  failed reason: unknown-capabilities
  -------------------------
  Modes   |      supported: allowed: any; preferred: none
          |        current: allowed: any; preferred: none

pi5-dev:~ $ nmcli -o

ttyACM0: unavailable
        "Intel MODEM + 2 CDC-ACM + 3 CDC-NCM + SS"
        modem (cdc_acm, cdc_ncm), hw


pi5-dev:~ $ mmcli -L
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [manufacturer unknown] model unknown


pi5-dev:~ $ pinctrl
 0: ip    pu | hi // ID_SDA/GPIO0 = input
 1: ip    pu | hi // ID_SCL/GPIO1 = input
 2: a3    pu | hi // GPIO2 = SDA1
 3: a3    pu | hi // GPIO3 = SCL1
 4: ip    pn | lo // GPIO4 = input
 5: no    pu | -- // GPIO5 = none
 6: no    pu | -- // GPIO6 = none
 7: op dh pu | hi // GPIO7 = output
 8: op dh pu | hi // GPIO8 = output
 9: a0    pn | lo // GPIO9 = SPI0_MISO
10: a0    pn | lo // GPIO10 = SPI0_MOSI
11: a0    pn | lo // GPIO11 = SPI0_SCLK
12: no    pd | -- // GPIO12 = none
13: no    pd | -- // GPIO13 = none
14: no    pd | -- // GPIO14 = none
15: no    pd | -- // GPIO15 = none
16: no    pd | -- // GPIO16 = none
17: no    pd | -- // GPIO17 = none
18: no    pd | -- // GPIO18 = none
19: no    pd | -- // GPIO19 = none
20: no    pd | -- // GPIO20 = none
21: no    pd | -- // GPIO21 = none
22: no    pd | -- // GPIO22 = none
23: no    pd | -- // GPIO23 = none
24: no    pd | -- // GPIO24 = none
25: no    pd | -- // GPIO25 = none
26: no    pd | -- // GPIO26 = none
27: no    pd | -- // GPIO27 = none
28: op dh pd | hi // PCIE_RP1_WAKE/GPIO28 = output
29: no    pu | hi // FAN_TACH/GPIO29 = none
30: no    pu | -- // HOST_SDA/GPIO30 = none
31: no    pu | -- // HOST_SCL/GPIO31 = none
32: op dh pd | hi // ETH_RST_N/GPIO32 = output
33: no    pd | lo // GPIO33 = none
34: op dl pd | lo // CD0_IO0_MICCLK/GPIO34 = output
35: no    pd | lo // CD0_IO0_MICDAT0/GPIO35 = none
36: no    pd | lo // RP1_PCIE_CLKREQ_N/GPIO36 = none
37: no    pd | lo // GPIO37 = none
38: ip    pd | hi // CD0_SDA/GPIO38 = input
39: ip    pd | hi // CD0_SCL/GPIO39 = input
40: ip    pd | hi // CD1_SDA/GPIO40 = input
41: ip    pd | hi // CD1_SCL/GPIO41 = input
42: a2    pd | hi // USB_VBUS_EN/GPIO42 = VBUS_EN1
43: a2    pu | hi // USB_OC_N/GPIO43 = VBUS_OC1
44: op dh pd | hi // RP1_STAT_LED/GPIO44 = output
45: ip    pd | lo // FAN_PWM/GPIO45 = input
46: op dl pd | lo // CD1_IO0_MICCLK/GPIO46 = output
47: no    pd | lo // 2712_WAKE/GPIO47 = none
48: no    pd | lo // CD1_IO1_MICDAT1/GPIO48 = none
49: op dl pd | lo // EN_MAX_USB_CUR/GPIO49 = output
50: no    pd | -- // GPIO50 = none
51: no    pd | -- // GPIO51 = none
52: no    pu | -- // GPIO52 = none
53: no    pu | hi // GPIO53 = none
100: ip    pd | lo // GPIO0 = input
101: op dh pu | hi // 2712_BOOT_CS_N/GPIO1 = output
102: a6    pn | hi // 2712_BOOT_MISO/GPIO2 = VC_SPI0_MISO
103: a5    pn | hi // 2712_BOOT_MOSI/GPIO3 = VC_SPI0_MOSI
104: a6    pn | lo // 2712_BOOT_SCLK/GPIO4 = VC_SPI0_SCLK
105: ip    pd | lo // GPIO5 = input
106: ip    pd | lo // GPIO6 = input
107: ip    pd | lo // GPIO7 = input
108: ip    pd | lo // GPIO8 = input
109: ip    pd | lo // GPIO9 = input
110: ip    pd | lo // GPIO10 = input
111: ip    pd | lo // GPIO11 = input
112: ip    pd | lo // GPIO12 = input
113: ip    pd | lo // GPIO13 = input
114: a1    pd | hi // PCIE_SDA/GPIO14 = SPI_S_MOSI_OR_BSC_S_SDA
115: a1    pd | hi // PCIE_SCL/GPIO15 = SPI_S_SCK_OR_BSC_S_SCL
116: ip    pd | lo // GPIO16 = input
117: ip    pd | lo // GPIO17 = input
118: ip    pd | lo // GPIO18 = input
119: ip    pd | lo // GPIO19 = input
120: ip    pu | hi // PWR_GPIO/GPIO20 = input
121: ip    pd | lo // 2712_G21_FS/GPIO21 = input
122: ip    pd | lo // GPIO22 = input
123: ip    pd | lo // GPIO23 = input
124: a3    pn | lo // BT_RTS/GPIO24 = UART_RTS_0
125: a4    pu | lo // BT_CTS/GPIO25 = UART_CTS_0
126: a4    pn | hi // BT_TXD/GPIO26 = UART_TXD_0
127: a4    pu | hi // BT_RXD/GPIO27 = UART_RXD_0
128: op dh pd | hi // WL_ON/GPIO28 = output
129: op dh pd | hi // BT_ON/GPIO29 = output
130: a4    pn | hi // WIFI_SDIO_CLK/GPIO30 = SD2_CLK
131: a4    pu | hi // WIFI_SDIO_CMD/GPIO31 = SD2_CMD
132: a4    pd | hi // WIFI_SDIO_D0/GPIO32 = SD2_DAT0
133: a3    pu | hi // WIFI_SDIO_D1/GPIO33 = SD2_DAT1
134: a4    pn | hi // WIFI_SDIO_D2/GPIO34 = SD2_DAT2
135: a3    pn | hi // WIFI_SDIO_D3/GPIO35 = SD2_DAT3
200: ip    pd | hi // RP1_SDA/AON_GPIO0 = input
201: ip    pd | hi // RP1_SCL/AON_GPIO1 = input
202: op dh pd | hi // RP1_RUN/AON_GPIO2 = output
203: op dh pd | hi // SD_IOVDD_SEL/AON_GPIO3 = output
204: op dh pd | hi // SD_PWR_ON/AON_GPIO4 = output
205: a6    pu | lo // SD_CDET_N/AON_GPIO5 = SD_CARD_PRES_G
206: ip    pd | hi // SD_FLG_N/AON_GPIO6 = input
207: ip    pd | lo // AON_GPIO7 = input
208: ip    pd | lo // 2712_WAKE/AON_GPIO8 = input
209: op dh pd | hi // 2712_STAT_LED/AON_GPIO9 = output
210: ip    pd | lo // AON_GPIO10 = input
211: ip    pd | lo // AON_GPIO11 = input
212: ip    pd | lo // PMIC_INT/AON_GPIO12 = input
213: a3    pu | hi // UART_TX_FS/AON_GPIO13 = VC_TXD0
214: a3    pu | hi // UART_RX_FS/AON_GPIO14 = VC_RXD0
215: ip    pd | lo // AON_GPIO15 = input
216: ip    pu | hi // AON_GPIO16 = input
232: a1    -- | hi // HDMI0_SCL/AON_SGPIO0 = HDMI_TX0_BSC_SCL
233: a1    -- | hi // HDMI0_SDA/AON_SGPIO1 = HDMI_TX0_BSC_SDA
234: a1    -- | hi // HDMI1_SCL/AON_SGPIO2 = HDMI_TX1_BSC_SCL
235: a1    -- | hi // HDMI1_SDA/AON_SGPIO3 = HDMI_TX1_BSC_SDA
236: a2    -- | hi // PMIC_SCL/AON_SGPIO4 = BSC_M2_SCL
237: a2    -- | hi // PMIC_SDA/AON_SGPIO5 = BSC_M2_SDA

